# Angular controller inheritance scoping issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, prototypal-inheritance

The goal here is to have two different directives that are technically siblings share functionality.  I will either use one *or* the other, never one *inside* the other.

However, the second directive will have all the capability of the first with some small additions.  Because of this, I would like the functionality to *inherit* from the "Parent" directive to the "Child".

I'm achieving this by re-using the same directive definition object from the Parent on the Child, with the exception of the controller/template fields being changed.

This was all working well up until I hit the watchers from my `ParentDirCtrl`.  For some reason the watcher seems to be set up correctly watching `mydir.obj1` and yet somehow inside the watcher callback function `mydir.obj1` becomes undefined.

I'm assuming something about `_.extend`/`$controller` is changing how the `$scope`s work so `mydir.obj1` isn't defined in the `ParentDirCtrl`, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/HWlwva1OIntB7h8s7JSs?p=preview)

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

// lodash
.constant('_', _)

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.obj = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
  };
})


.controller('ParentDirCtrl', function($scope) {
  var mydir = this;

  mydir.doStuffInParent = function() {
    alert('executed from the parent directive');
  }

  $scope.$watch('mydir.obj1', function() {
    // ====================================
    //              ERROR
    // Why is 'mydir.obj1' undefined when
    // occupation is set?  
    // ====================================
    mydir.obj1.occupation = 'Meteorologist';
  });
})


.directive('parentDirective', parentDirective)


.directive('childDirective', function() {
  // borrow the directive definition object from the parent directive
  var parentDDO = parentDirective();

  // uodate the template and controller for our new directive
  parentDDO.template = [
    '<div>', 
      '<p ng-click="mydir.doStuffInParent()">{{mydir.obj1.name}}</p>',
      '<p ng-click="mydir.doStuffInChild()">{{mydir.obj1.age}}</p>',
    '</div>'
    ].join('');

  parentDDO.controller = function($scope, $controller, _) {
      // extend 'this' with the Parent's controller
      var mydir = _.extend(this, $controller('ParentDirCtrl', { $scope: $scope }));

      mydir.doStuffInChild = function() {
        alert("executed from the child directive");
      };
  }; 

  return parentDDO;
});


// this will be moved to the top during declaration hoisting
function parentDirective() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      obj1: '=',
    },
    template: '<div>{{mydir.obj1}}</div>',
    controller: 'ParentDirCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'mydir',
  };
}
```

Comment: If they are essentially the same why can't you just differentiate functionality all in one by setting an attribute?

Comment: The child is going to have some functions that overwrite the parent's and then a bunch of functionality simply not needed in the parent.  Additionally it's going to have some watchers for attributes that don't exist on the parent.

That being said, 100% of the functionality in the parent is needed in the child.  It would take a lot of conditionals to control all of this in a single directive.

Comment: `var mydir` is `this` extended with the properties from the parent controller.  My understanding is that this is the way to inherit from another controller.

Comment: oops i read it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj1` is populated on the child controller instance - that's why `mydir.obj1` is undefined in the parent watcher. You can access `obj1` directly via scope or by using the reference passed into the watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('mydir.obj1', function(val) {
    $scope.mydir.obj1.occupation = 'Meteorologist';
    // or
    val.occupation = 'Meteorologis';
});
```

There is no scope inheritance here - both controllers operate on the same scope. **Controller-AS** syntax is what confuses you - I'd get rid of it to make things clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and updated to ditch controller-As syntax.  The error went away but now the watcher doesn't fire at all:  https://plnkr.co/edit/oVCoPW?p=preview  It seems that after the `$timeout` that watcher should fire.

Comment: To catch changes made by `angular.copy` - set the third parameter (`objectEquality`) of the `$watch` method to `true`. `angular.copy` does not change the reference of the destination.

Comment: ah, duh.  Should have been using $watchCollection.  Thanks!